# adding €-sign in valueBox() in RShiny

Tags: r, euro

My `valueBox()` in the server is generated as:

```
valueBox(winterMean, subtitle = "Mean Winter Performance", color = "black")
```

What I want to have the subtitle **Mean Winter Performance   € / MWh**, but unfortunately I don't know how to add the €-sign. The unicode for the € is `&#8364;` but this doesn't work here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [unicode UTF-16 encoding](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+20AC):

```
valueBox(100, subtitle = "Mean Winter Performance \u20ac/MWh ", color = "black")
```

Comment: This works! Thank you. Do you now how i can add a linebreak before the €-sign?

Comment: I tried the usual `\n` for linebreak, but it doesn't seem to work in a valueBox.